# Kotlin Editing List

Tags: kotlin

What is the best way to edit an immutable `List` in Kotlin?

I understand that `List` is not actually immutable, but if I'm passing a `List` into into a function and I need that entire list minus a single element, is there a supported way to handle that? What about if I want that entire list with an additional element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are creating the list yourself, instead of calling `listOf("foo", "bar")` call `mutableListOf("foo", "bar")` to get an instance of a `MutableList`.

If you get the list, e.g. as a parameter to a method, call `toMutableList()` on it to get a mutable **copy**.

Alternatively use one of the many built-in extension methods like `map()` or `filter()` to get a **new**  list with the modifed elements. For example, to get a list without the first n elements use `drop(n)`. To get only the first n elements call `take(n)`. [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html#extension-functions) you can find more of the built-in extension methods.

If you need to join two lists, just use the plus operator like this: `val newList = list1 + list2`.

Note, that modifying lists that are parameters to your methods can be a code smell. That's why all the built-in methods return copies. Also your asumption

> I understand that List is not actually immutable

is wrong. As you can see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/edc471c8ec2454058b06180dc2a2c9af90320915/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/JUtil.kt#L68), the standard library will return an immutable empty list if you call `listOf()` without arguments.

In Java the `List` interface is mutable per default which can lead to exceptions when you try to modify an immutable list such as one that was created by calling `Arrays.asList()`. That's why in Kotlin the opposite is the case.

Comment: If you have an ArrayList, and you pass it as a List, that List isn't actually immutable. That's what I meant by that it isn't actually immutable.

Comment: That's right. From a type system point of view however, a mutable list is always an immutable list while the opposite is not the case.

Comment: Kotlin `List<T>` interface is not `Immutable` but rather `read-only` ... small difference to some, huge to others.  `MutableList<T>` is obviously mutable.

Comment: I didn't know you could join lists like that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with immutable lists, what you want to do is create new lists. So in your case, if you want a list without an element, then filter that element out (in Kotlin you can use the filter function) and return the new list.